# Xamarin Visual Studio createcertfromfile path no working

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have been working all day, I need to make an ssl connection to mosquito mqtt broker in c# using xamarin.

I am trying to CreateFromCertFile(path to cert) ......

However everything I try won't work.

The file is located at C:\Cert\MyCARoot.cer

I have tried CreateFromCertFile(@"c:\Cert\MyCARoot.cer");

and

CreateFromCertFile("c:\\Cert\\MyCARoot.cer");

The error I keep getting is

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/C:\Cert\MyCARoot.cer"

Basically it adds a "/" and then says the path is no good.  I just don't get it everything I read says this should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the problem with paths in xamarin, however there is a problem.  I did find a solution.

1. Make sure your working from an Activity.
2. add the file your wanting to work with in your assets folder (right click add existing)
3. Instantiate an AssetManager Class -- AssetManager assets = this.Assets;

Now this is where my application may be different from others because I wanted a byte[] created from my asset which I could use to instantiate a x509....2 certificate class.

I used Stream and MemoryStream to get my desired results see below

```
 AssetManager assets = this.Assets;
 using (Stream input = assets.Open("ca-bundle.crt"))
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int read;
                while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                data = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

I then instantiated my connection class with my new byte [], and bing, bang, boom I had an ssl connection to my mosquitto mqtt broker.

Other applications I saw that assets.Open("fileInAsset") worked in place of the path to file for other operations.

Good luck