# using Xamarin Visual Studio C# using M2Mqtt to connect to Mosquitto mqtt with ssl

Tags: c#, xamarin, mqtt, mosquitto

I am trying to connect to my mosquitto mqtt broker in an Xamarin c# application using M2Mqtt.

I am having a difficult time creating the x509 certificate in my program

SEE --- My other question

[Xamarin Visual Studio createcertfromfile path no working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45090618/xamarin-visual-studio-createcertfromfile-path-no-working)

But I wanted to float this question just to see if any one out there has done this.  I have spent 2 days making absolutely no progress.

My only concern is encrypting the communication between the mobile device and my mosquito broker.

I have secured the broker with mosquitto-auth-plug and I can't be sending the credentials over the air.

One other question -- I am not concerned with verifying the mobile user I just want to create a secure encrypted connection with my broker, so I am not going to need my users to get any certificates or anything?? correct

-----Edit for hardilib

I have a mosquitto broker running on a centos 7 server.  I have configured the broker to accept ssl/tls connections and have used mosquitto-auth-plug for user security.

I have a mobile application written in c# Xamarin with visual studio 2017 enterprise edition.

I have very good non encrypted communication between my mqtt broker and mobile application using M2Mqtt client.

I need encrypted communication between the mobile application and the broker for this to work in a real world situation.

I have tried to follow the only information I can find at

http://embedded101.com/Blogs/PaoloPatierno/entryid/366/MQTT-over-SSL-TLS-with-the-M2Mqtt-library-and-the-Mosquitto-broker

I have it all complete except the part

**The CA certificate was included in a resource file (Resources.resx) and, once read as a byte stream is provided to the X509Certificate constructor class, in order to obtain a valid X.509 certificate for the MqttClient.**

Client Connection String

```
MqttClient("ppatierno-PC", MqttClient.MQTT_BROKER_DEFAULT_SSL_PORT, true, new X509Certificate(Resources.m2mqtt_ca));
```

I haven't been able to create the x509Certificate because I don't know how to create the resource file.

And when I try to create the certificate from file none of the paths I try to use work -- See other question above.

Has anyone successfully done what I am explaining above or have another way to secure the communication between the application and the server if you have please help.

Thanks

Comment: There really isn't a clear question here, please read the doc about asking good questions (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see if this can be improved

Comment: Read the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out you can use AssetManager class to retrieve assets from you xamarin solutions directory.

see my other post for more complete instructions

[Xamarin Visual Studio createcertfromfile path no working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45090618/xamarin-visual-studio-createcertfromfile-path-no-working)